# Deletion in a blockchain network

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I was working on a crud D-app, coding in solidity. I am unable to figure out how does deletion and updation work on the blockchain network?

Comment: There's no physical deletion nor retrospective mutation of data on committed blocks. Logical deletion / mutation needs to be done through appending new transactions to the contract and handled by your contract code. The pattern is essentially the same as [event sourcing](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-sourcing.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is none. You can only add new transactions. You have to add a new transaction saying something was deleted or updated, and then, whoever is displaying the data needs to see the new transaction and stop displaying the data.

If you are writing a smart contract, you can delete or update data in storage, but other people can still see that data since it's in the previous transactions - there is no privacy.